# Horizontal UICollectionView with Header on Top

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift2

I'm kind of stuck with a problem here. I need to create a horizontal scroll Collection View, but when I select to add its header, xcode sticks it on the left side of the cells and I need it to be above the cells, as on the vertical scroll.

Any tips?

Comment: Just add a simple uiview above your collectionview.

Comment: Instead of using the header, add a UIView on the top of the collectionView to act as its header, right?

I thought about it but was hoping there was any customization I could do on the collectionView itself...

But I think I'll stick with the UIView. It should do the trick for me.

Thanks Alex!

Comment: Yes, it would be faster than implement subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout and implement the same behavior there.

Answer (score -1):

embed UICollectionViews in a UITableView like so: [image]